# Tokenizing an s-expression in C

Tags: c, parsing, lisp, tokenize, s-expression

I'm trying to create my own Lisp interpreter and have run into some issues with the parsing of s-expressions. My initial thought was to tokenize the expression and handle one bit at a time. [I came across some code to do this](https://github.com/kimtg/ToyLisp/blob/master/ToyLisp.c#L253) after failing with my own attempts, however I am confused with it's output.

```
int lex(const char *str, const char **start, const char **end)
{
    const char *ws = " \t\r\n";
    const char *delim = "() \t\r\n";
    const char *prefix = "()'`";

    str += strspn(str, ws);

    if (str[0] == '\0') {
        *start = *end = NULL;
        return 1;
    }

    *start = str;

    if (strchr(prefix, str[0]) != NULL)
        *end = *start + 1;
    else
        *end = *start + strcspn(str, delim);

    return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
const char *input = "(foo bar 17 '(a b c) 2)";

char *token;
char *p = input;

lex(p, &token, &p);

while(token != NULL)
{
    printf("%.*s\n", (int)(p - input), token);
    lex(p, &token, &p);
}
```

[Output:](http://ideone.com/cZYGN2)

```
(
foo 
bar 17 '
17 '(a b c)
'(a b c) 2)
(a b c) 2)
a b c) 2)
b c) 2)
c) 2)
) 2)
2)
)
```

Looking at the code, I had expected it, for example, to output `17` and not `17 '(a b c)` or to output `2` and not `2)`. What is causing this and how can I fix it? I'm also open to advice if tokenization isn't the best solution in this case.

On a second note, is a parameter like `str` absolutely necessary? Would the `start` and `end` parameters not be sufficient, for no data prior to `start` is necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple typo.

```
 printf("%.*s\n", (int)(p - input), token);
```

Should be

```
 printf("%.*s\n", (int)(p - token), token);
```

`str` is an input argument and `start` and `end` are output arguments. You could make `start` an inout argument, but not everyone likes those.

In any case, the returned token starts at `start` and its length is `end - start`, which is why the printf length argument needs to be `p - token`.

Comment: Well, this was embarrassing... Thanks for catching that.